# How to fix ubuntu screen graphic glitch after boot from sleep mode?

Tags: boot, suspend, amd-graphics, motherboard

This problem occurs on my computer after I changed my motherboard.
Also after clicking on sleep mode button. The pc won't sleep properly and its fan and cpu is running and with  black screen. After clicking mouse and keyboard button screen wakes on with appearing  some graphic glitches on it as picture shown below in link.
And also provide how to debug this problem.
Specification:

1. OS :Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
2. Graphic Card: AMD RV710
3. Processor: Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU E5200 @ 2.50GHz × 2
4. Motherboard: MB-G31

![This is screen looks like after not sleep properly][1]

[1]
https://pasteboard.co/K09Q5gl.jpg

Comment: Please edit the question and add hardware specifications, particularly the graphics.

Comment: With such old hardware issues are to be expected. On top of that it's 32-bit so you're using a the last still supported Ubuntu release for 32-bit. Standard Ubuntu is too much for such hardware but unfortunately the flavors you should be running (Lubuntu, Xubuntu...) are already EoL. You need to consider Debian or AntiX moving forward.

Comment: The image link is invalid. Please upload it here instead of hosting on a third-party site.

Comment: Thanks  @ChanganAuto for answering. Some details added. And I think it's some motherboard driver issue is there. And is there any way to debug this process issue.

Comment: @tripleee sorry but I can't it needs 10+ reputation to upload an image.